# Como puedo hacer que un popup se ejecute solo la primera vez / Jquery

Tags: jquery

$(document).ready(function(){

```
 createCyberbox();
```

});

Como puedo hacer que la función createCyberbox() se ejecute solo al cargar la pagina pero al recargarla no se muestre ( es un popup)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día, puedes hacer uso del `localStorage` que te permite utilizar los datos persisten almacenados entre de las diferentes sesiones de navegación para que se almacene dentro de el, de la siguiente manera:

Validamos si la variable ya esta almacenada y en caso no la este lo muestra, de otra manera no lo mostrara.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
       var isshow = localStorage.getItem('isshow');
       if (isshow== null) {
           localStorage.setItem('isshow', 1);

           // Muestras el popup aqui
           createCyberbox();
       }
});
```